# Chrome window.print() missing page elements

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

I am currently having an issue with Chrome (47.0.2526.111, OS X) not rendering the whole page both in preview and when printed when using a button, with a onclick=window.print() event.

Certain elements are not rendered, such as some paragraph blocks and occasionally some images.

This issue is not replicated in an other browser, and oddly enough only appeared once I added a print button, and the behaviour is not observable when using Ctrl+P or in the Chrome print stylesheet media emulation.

The issue seems very temperamental, if I have rendered the print view via a Ctrl+P I am able to go back and use the print button successfully with all elements rendering.

Comment: are u using a separate css file with `media="print"` or not?

Comment: yes I am using a seperate print stylesheet

Comment: Still experiencing this issue, as mentioned above, I do use a seperate print media stylesheet. Issue cannot be reproduced when using Ctrl + P, and no problem whatsoever with Safari, Firefox or even IE11.

Comment: @Trix, as mentioned above, it does not.

Answer (score 2):

Use separate `print.css` file for `media="print"`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="path/to/print.css" media="print">
```

in your media queries:

```
@media print{
    div.print{
      width: 100%;
    }
}
```