# Missing elements when using selenium chrome driver to automatically 'Save as PDF'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to automatically save a PDF file created with `pdftohtmlEX` (https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX) using the selenium (chrome) webdriver.

It almost works except captions of figures and sometimes even part of the figures are missing.

Manually saved:

[image: Manually saved]

Automatically saved using selenium & chrome webdriver:
[image: Saved using selenium & chromedriver]

**Here is my code** (you need the chromium webdriver (http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) in the same folder as this script):

```
import json
from selenium import webdriver

# print settings: save as pdf, 'letter' formatting
appState = """{
    "recentDestinations": [
        {
            "id": "Save as PDF",
            "origin": "local"
        }
    ],
    "mediaSize": {
        "height_microns": 279400,
        "name": "NA_LETTER",
        "width_microns": 215900,
        "custom_display_name": "Letter"
    },
    "selectedDestinationId": "Save as PDF",
    "version": 2
}"""

appState = json.loads(appState)
profile = {"printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState": json.dumps(appState)}
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', profile)
# Enable automatically pressing the print button in print preview
# https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/
chrome_options.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')

driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
driver.get('http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/intro.html')
driver.execute_script('window.print();')
driver.quit()
```

Sometimes when I manually print this happens, too. But if I then change any of the printing options, the  preview reloads and the image captions are there again and stay there no matter what options I further enable/disable.

[image: Chrome printing settings]

#### What I tried so far:

- different Chrome webdriver versions (71, 72, 73) from this site: http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
- enable background graphics by adding '"isCssBackgroundEnabled": true' to the appState

Comment: if you are seeing this problem when you "manually print" as well it means you have a bug.  The real problem is probably that Selenium is very quick and it's replicating the thing that happens occasionally when you do it manually

Comment: That is a good point! If I disable 'kiosk-printing' so that everything but the final klick on 'Save PDF' is automated, no matter how long I wait or what print settings I change, the missing elements never appear... which is in contrast to when I manually print. So there seems to be a difference between the Chrome.app and the chrome driver. It's either a missing preference or a bug...

Comment: might be a silly question, but have you tried adding a manual wait time after the get? Selenium does not nessecarily wait for all elements to render properly, and `print` should only print what is rendered at the moment of call. 
All the PNG files appears to be loaded asynchronously, and Selenium may not be waiting for them to be downloaded and rendered.

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention, also tried that already :) The thing is, on the website (pdf) all elements are immediately there, it is only once I go to the printing preview that they are missing...

Comment: Problem with your print CSS settings?

Comment: Maybe... Do you mean something else than `isCssBackgroundEnabled`? Enabling that does not make the elements appear, unfortunately.

Comment: I think the CSS setting might be it. I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984081/chrome-window-print-missing-page-elements. Any idea how I load my own CSS settings with selenium?

Comment: Add link for later: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37318538/apply-css-to-printwindow-print-in-javascript

Comment: I am not sure how to fix your issue but wanted to say that I appreciate your work, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, through fiddeling around, I came by the solution by accident. I don't really understand why, but enabling the 'PrintBrowser mode' ("Enables PrintBrowser mode, in which everything renders as though printed.") solves the issue. This may or may have to do with CSS loading properly.

I just need to add `chrome_options.add_argument('--enable-print-browser')` and all elements are there!