# I can't set chrome to default saving option as a PDF(python, selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, pdf, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to save pages as PDF, but cannot set "id" to "Save as PDF"(chrome driver's version is 98). There are many similar examples on stack overflow, but that solutions didn't work.
I can set download.dfrault_directory, it doesn't matter, only "Save as PDF" bothering me.
[this is window what i want to control or apply settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHdDe.png)
I already reffered this ->
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/chrome/common/pref_names.cc
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59953341/18220200

this is my code. I can't find wrong points, would appreciate any advice.

```
#Chromedriver pdf print setting
chromeoptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chromeSettings = {"recentDestinations": [{
    "id" : "Save as PDF",
    "origin" : "local",
    "account" : ""}],
"selectedDestinationID" : "Save as PDF",
"version" : 2,
}
chromeoptions.add_argument('--enable-print-browser')
chromeoptions.add_argument("--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection")
chromeoptions.add_argument("safebrowsing-disable-extension-blacklist")
prefs = {'printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState' : json.dumps(chromeSettings)}
chromeoptions.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
chromeoptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
    "download.default_directory": r"filepath",
    'behavior': 'allow',
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    'download.prompt_for_download': False,
    'download.extensions_to_open': 'pdf:xls:xml',
    'safebrowsing.enabled': True,
    'popups' : False
})
```

+I added my codes, 'print part'

```
clickByXpath('//print_button')
# Open chrome print window
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.press('enter')
filename = '\Report' + str(filename+1)
time.sleep(7) #wait for 'save as' window
pyautogui.typewrite(constants.FILE_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION + filename)
pyautogui.press('enter')
time.sleep(1)
driver.switch_to.window(now_window)
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'w')
```

Comment: please add all the code and the error that is thrown or what you have tried so far which fails.

Comment: @D.L there's NO ERROR MESSAGES, so i'm confused... and I added my code(for print), but I think it's useless.

Comment: @KJ But it's test(automated) browser, so chrome's settings are all... default set. they can't remember the last settings.